# VS code:tasks.json, the ";" symbol is interpreted as "';'" into the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

After installing VS Code Version: 1.85.2 (Universal), the ";" symbol in the line of arguments(args) is interpreted into the terminal as "';'". Consequently, after running c++ file the terminal can't run the commands.

The tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": 
    [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",

                "${file}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/glad.c",
                "-I/${workspaceFolder}/include",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-L/${workspaceFolder}/include",
                "-lglfw.3",
                ";",
                "install_name_tool",
                "-change",
                "@rpath/libglfw.3.dylib",
                "${workspaceFolder}/lib/libglfw.3.dylib",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/main"
                
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

The terminal after running the c++ file:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always /Users/user/Desktop/OpenGLProjects/EBO/src/main.cpp /Users/user/Desktop/OpenGLProjects/EBO/src/glad.c -I//Users/user/Desktop/OpenGLProjects/EBO/include -o /Users/user/Desktop/OpenGLProjects/EBO/src/main -L//Users/user/Desktop/OpenGLProjects/EBO/include -lglfw.3 ';' install_name_tool -change @rpath/libglfw.3.dylib /Users/user/Desktop/OpenGLProjects/EBO/lib/libglfw.3.dylib /Users/user/Desktop/OpenGLProjects/EBO/src/main
clang: error: unknown argument: '-change' clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated] clang: error: no such file or directory: 'install_name_tool' clang: error: no such file or directory: '@rpath/libglfw.3.dylib'
```

As you can see, the ";" symbol is put into these grave accents.

ChatGPT suggested me to rewrite my tasks.json file:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "${file}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/glad.c",
                "-I/${workspaceFolder}/include",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-L/${workspaceFolder}/include",
                "-lglfw.3",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "label": "Change install_name_tool",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "install_name_tool",
            "args": [
                "-change",
                "@rpath/libglfw.3.dylib",
                "${workspaceFolder}/lib/libglfw.3.dylib",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/main"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task to change install_name_tool"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

But it didn't work.
Would appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's shell syntax, and VS Code tasks are not generalized shell command executors (though there is a `shell` task type). If you want to run multiple commands in sequence, use the [compound tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks) feature.